# Site to organize one's thoughts?

Tags: organizer-software

I can't remember the name of the wonderful webapp that helps one organize one's thought by typing in lists and then freely moving bullet points around.

Searching for "organize thoughts" leads to many lists of sites but the one I'm looking for isn't listed.

I think it as "write" in its name or does a play on words with the word "write", but I'm not sure.

When in use, it just presents a full white page.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: do give a try to Organisr (http://organi.sr)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

The term you are looking for is "[mindmapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map)"